# Pure functions and I/O

Tags: functional-programming

I have been reading up on functional programming, and I understand the concept of pure functions and immutable objects and why they apply in functional programming.

I am a bit fuzzy on when and why a function performing I/O will be considered impure:

- I/O input - If the result of the function does not depend on an I/O input such as a user input or a file read, will it still be considered impure and why?
- I/O output - if my pure function has a few alerts or a few system outs, but always returns the same result for the same argument(s), will it still be considered impure and why?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: "*I/O input - If the result of the function does not depend on an I/O input*" - then why would it take any input? Also, what does "input" mean to you - does the function wait until the user inputs something? Does the function *consume* from the input buffer (thereby changing it)?

Comment: Input as I used it here would be reading a file or an input stream or stdin.

Comment: "*I/O output - if my pure function has a few system outs, but always returns the same result*" - then it might be considered pure, depending on what parts of the system you are currently reasoning about. Computing a function on a real machine always involves state mutations (in RAM, CPU etc) that you might care about or not. If there's no way your program can observe its own output, you can indeed ignore it. For example, hooking a debugger or profiler into your program will make it output some logging data, but your function stays pure.

Comment: @programmeravi: Reading a file should not change any state (depending on your OS), so when you don't use what you did read you can (and should) just omit the read without changing anything, and one might consider the program pure even with the read that affects nothing. Reading from a stream (including stdin) however does *consume* data, making it unavailable to other readers and advancing the source, so it is a form of output at the same time and cannot be considered pure even when you throw the read data away.

Comment: So from your response bergi, it seems that I/O only renders a function impure if there is an observable impact in the state of the shared resources such as CPU/memory or some global shared object that other threads would be able to observe  -- but none of the literature I read regarding pure functions vis a vis functional programming makes this qualification... a huge missing point that should be made clear right? Also do you have anything to say about referential transparency (see below) - is that affected if the I/O performed by the function is not observable?

Comment: "pure" means the same thing as "referentially transparent". All of its input (arguments) and output (return values) must be explicitly modelled with the chosen [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)), and not depend on/affect anything else. The word "chosen" is important here: when arguing about programs and their equivalence, we get to decide which parts we care about and which not. When executing real programs on real computers, we cannot avoid changing internal states of the machine - but often those are things we want to ignore. Is `1 + 1` the same as `2`?

Comment: You probably say Yes, but the first expressions took 3 CPU instructions to compute while the second took only one. Do we care? No, we want to consider them equal, so we ignore the instruction count. It's the same with I/O: you have to define a system boundary. Which are the effects (state mutations) that you care about, and want to reason about their equality, and which do you want to ignore? Some examples: order of OS syscalls. Nanosecond timing of OS syscalls. Debug output to stdout. Mutations of shared memory. Writing logfiles. Number of used threads. Reading static configuration files…

Answer (score 3):

Pure functions must be [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency).

Any function that involves any IO is not referentially transparent, since its call cannot be replaced with the returned result.

> I/O input - If the result of the function does not depend on an I/O input such as a user input or a file read, will it still be considered impure and why?

If it does not - then simply remove any IO reads.

> I/O output - if my pure function has a few alerts or a few system outs, but always returns the same result for the same argument(s), will it still be considered impure and why?

It won't be - because of the side effect.

Answer (score 0):

> I/O output - if my pure function has a few alerts or a few system outs, but always returns the same result for the same argument(s), will it still be considered impure and why?

It's not pure anymore, because the side effect changes "the world" so the result is not "the same" anymore.

Harmless example of changing the world: before your function computes, you had 2 lines output on the screen. After computation, there are 3.

Not so harmless example of changing the world: When your program started (which uses your "almost pure" function a lot), you had several gigabytes freespace on your C: drive. Unfortunately, it was started with output redirected to some file on the C: drive, and after a few hours the C: drive run full. This caused some planned nightly run of an important acccounting job to fail. Result: your company didn't have some important numbers at hand at the right time, and it lost money. And you lost your job.