# Writting to file without returning an IO() element

Tags: haskell

Would it be possible to write in a file without returning an IO() element in the function.
For the moment, I am only able to write to a file by returning IO() in my function f.

```hs
f:: Type -> IO()
f sequent = do 
    --let result = ...
    let file = "tmp/log.txt"
    writeToFile file ("TIMES rule: " ++  (show result))


writeToFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO()
writeToFile file content = do 
    x <- SIO.readFile file
    writeFile file ("\n"++content)
    appendFile file x
```

Would it be possible to have something as follows instead,

```hs
f:: Type -> String
f sequent = do 
    --let result = ...
    let file = "tmp/log.txt"
    -- do without returning
    writeToFile file ("TIMES rule: " ++  (show result))
    -- return the result
    result
```

Comment: No, the idea of `IO` is to encapsulate logic that has side-effects in an `IO` container. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892814/how-to-convert-io-int-to-string-in-haskell `IO` is not the *result* of an `IO` action, you can think of it as a collection of steps to get a result.

Comment: In Haskell, any function that does IO must return an IO-related type. This is enforced by the type system, there's no way around it.

Comment: Is there writeFile function not returning IO() in haskell ?

Comment: No, and there isn't supposed to be.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46743512, https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_IO_for_Imperative_Programmers, https://wiki.haskell.org/Non-strict_semantics.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7154518, https://stackoverflow.com/q/41522491.

Answer (score 4):

This is intentional. The idea behind `IO` is that you can see from the type of the function whether it will perform side effects.